# "Bad return type in lambda expression: String cannot be converted to void" in .forEach method

Tags: java, oop, strong-typing

I have a class `Users` with, among others, a `List` of `user` objects, the following method, which is supposed to

1. build a `list` of `String`
2. check if an incoming `String` is contained in that list.

```java
public class Users {
    List<User> users;

    public Users(List<User> users) {
        this.users = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    #...

    public boolean checkUserExists(String targetUserID) {
        List<String> userIDS = users.forEach(user -> user.userID);
        return userIDS.contains(targetUserID);
    }
}
```

But, under the lambda expression, SonarLint shows the *"Bad return type in lambda expression: String cannot be converted to void"* error.

This is how the class `User` is implemented:

```java
package menus.DataStructures;

public class User {
    String userType;
    String userID;
    String userName;
    int userAge;

    protected User(String userType, String userID, String userName, int userAGe) {
        this.userType = userType;
        this.userID = userID;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userAge = userAGe;
    }
}
```

In my mind, there shouldn't be a problem, but I'm almost new to Java and I come from JS and Python. I have read answers addressing the same error message but due to my Java ignorance I haven't been able to understand anything.

What causes this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what you're looking for is `map` and not `forEach`:

```java
public boolean checkUserExists(String targetUserID) {
    List<String> userIDS = users.stream().map((user) -> user.userID).collect(Collectors.toList()) 
    // if you're using java 16+ you can replace .collect(...) with .toList();
    return userIDS.contains(targetUserID);
}
```

Comment: No need to collect, you can directly do `return users.stream().map(user -> user.userID).anyMatch(targetUserID::equals);`

Comment: And if you _did_ need to collect, a `Set` would be a better solution.

Comment: Note that if you have the option of using Groovy, you can say `var userIds = users*.userId` or `users.find { it.userId == targetId }`.